# Как организовать сборку для разных страниц со своими стилями?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Предположим у меня есть две страницы, на которых нужно организовать подключение разных файлов стилей. 
На входе, например, файлы style.scss и style-main.scss (каждый подключается к своей странице) и на выходе получились их соответствующие минифицированные версии. Пока сборка проходит в одном файле, и на выходе получается один минифицированный файл.

Вот текущий код таска:

```
gulp.task("css:build", function () {
return gulp.src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ["last 5 versions"],
        cascade: true
    }))
    .pipe(removeComments())
    .pipe(cssbeautify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(cssnano({
        zindex: false,
        discardComments: {
            removeAll: true
        }
    }))
    .pipe(rename("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(webserver.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, проблема заключается в том, что вы явно задаете имя выходного файла, поэтому файл у вас в итоге получается один.

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(scss({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', scss.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'],
            cascade: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/custom'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});

gulp.task('css-min', ['scss'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app/css/custom/*.css')
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

На выходе у вас должно получится несколько файлов стилей с префиксом `min`, т.е. сколько было в папке файлов столько на выходи получится, например, в вашем случае `style.min.css` и `style-main.min.css`

Comment: я нашел в чем еще проблема, у меня в path.src.css указан конкретный файл src/assets/sass/style.scss, как правильно будет указать второй?

Comment: Вы можете просто указать путь до папки, где лежат оба файла, и указать чтобы он брал все файлы с расширением `.scss`, например: `gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss')`

Comment: Пробовал, выбивает ошибку в консоли и вообще не создает минифицированный файл.

Comment: Я тут покопался у себя в исходниках, и нашел пример конфига. Изменил свой ответ, добавив этот код в качестве примера. =) Основной таск, который минифицирует файлы это `css-min`, перед запуском этого таска, предварительно запускается таск `scss`.

Comment: блин, разобрался вроде, работает, чуть душу дьяволу не продал :D спасибо. Только единственное не понял, почему нельзя все сделать в одном таске (как у меня типо), массив файлов тоже уже пробовал, не принимал.

Comment: я тут неожиданно и со своим блоком кода разобрался, и так не нашел причину почему оно не работало и почему заработало, магия блин какая-то.